# Old data flickering after hover on line graph Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

My problem is not making the chart, but when I input new values for the start freq and end freq, which are the first and last values of my x-axis array after calling getFreq(), the chart glitches when I hover, going back and forth between the old data and new data. Can anyone help me figure out how to delete the old data and make/update to a new chart where the chart doesn't flicker? My code is shown below.

If you want to test the graph
put 39.4 as attenuation, 0.1 as a, 0.05 as b, 0.16 for diameter, 15 for conductivity, and 25 and 125 as the start and end freq respectively. To test the flickering, just replace 25 with another number and hover over the graph.

```
let Conductivity = document.getElementById('Conductivity');
let StartFreq = document.getElementById('StartFreq');
let StopFreq = document.getElementById('StopFreq');
let a = document.getElementById('a');
let b = document.getElementById('b');
let unitInch = document.getElementById('unitInch');
let test = document.getElementById('test');
let diameter = document.getElementById('Diameter');
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');


function generateLabels(){
    // To generate the xa xis intervals
    let xaxis = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        let valToAppend = Math.round((parseFloat(StartFreq.value) + (parseFloat(StopFreq.value)-parseFloat(StartFreq.value)) / 10 * i)*100)/100;
        if (valToAppend <= parseFloat(StopFreq.value)){
            xaxis.push(valToAppend)
        }

    }
    return xaxis
}
function getFreq(){
    let x = generateLabels();
    let freq = [];
    let start = x[0];
    freq.push(start);
    let end = x[x.length - 1];
    for (let i=0; i < 4 * (end-start);i++){
        let lastfreq = freq[freq.length - 1];
        freq.push(lastfreq + 0.25)
    }
    // let rklen = freq.length;

    return freq
}


function getRS(){
    let RS = [];
    let freq = getFreq();
    freq.forEach(element =>{
        let RStoAppend = Math.sqrt((2*Math.PI*(Math.pow(10,9)*element)*(4*Math.PI*Math.pow(10,-7)))/(2*(parseFloat(Conductivity.value)*Math.pow(10,7))))     ;
        RS.push(RStoAppend)
    });
    return RS

}
function getRK(){
    let RK = [];
    let freq = getFreq();
    freq.forEach(element => {
        let RKtoappend = (2*Math.PI*(element * Math.pow(10,9))) / (3* Math.pow(10,8));
        RK.push(RKtoappend)
    });

    return RK
}
function getRbeta(){
    let Rbeta = [];
    let RK = getRK();
    RK.forEach(element => {
        let Rbetatoappend = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(element,2) - Math.pow((Math.PI/(parseFloat(a.value)*25.4/1000)),2));
        Rbeta.push(Rbetatoappend);
    });


    return Rbeta;
}
function getRatte(){
    let Ratte = [];
    let RS = getRS();
    let RK = getRK();
    let Rbeta = getRbeta();
    for (let i = 0; i < RS.length ;i++){
        let Rattetoappend = RS[i]*(2*(25.4/1000*parseFloat(b.value))*Math.pow(Math.PI,2)+Math.pow((parseFloat(a.value)*25.4/1000),3)*Math.pow(RK[i],2))/(Math.pow((parseFloat(a.value)*25.4/1000),3)*(25.4/1000*parseFloat(b.value))*Rbeta[i]*RK[i]*377)/(1000/25.4);
        Ratte.push(Rattetoappend);
    }
    // test.innerHTML = '<td id="test">' + Ratte + '<td>';

    return Ratte
}
function getRTE10(){
    let RTE10 = [];
    let Ratte = getRatte();
    Ratte.forEach(element => {
        if (isNaN(-20*Math.log10(Math.exp(-element)) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))) {
            RTE10.push(0)
        }
        else {
            RTE10.push(-20 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-element)) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))
        }
    });


    return RTE10
}
//////////////////////// For CTE11/////////////
function getk(){
    let k = [];
    let freq = getFreq();
    freq.forEach(element => {
        k.push(2*Math.PI*element*Math.pow(10,9)/(3*Math.pow(10,8)))
    });
    return k
}
function getbeta(){
    let beta = [];
    let k = getk();
    k.forEach(element => {
        beta.push(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(element,2)-Math.pow((1.8412/(parseFloat(diameter.value)/2*25.4/1000)),2)))
    });
    return beta
}
function getTE11_1(){
    let TE11_1 = [];
    let k = getk();
    let rs = getRS();
    let beta = getbeta();
    for (let i = 0; i < rs.length ;i++){
        TE11_1.push(rs[i]*(Math.pow((1.8412/(parseFloat(diameter.value)/2*25.4/1000)),2)+Math.pow(k[i],2)/(Math.pow(1.8414,2)-1))/((parseFloat(diameter.value)/2*25.4/1000)*k[i]*beta[i]*377)/(1000/25.4));
    }
    return TE11_1
}

function getCTE11(){
    let CTE11 = [];
    let TE11_1 = getTE11_1();
    TE11_1.forEach(element => {
        if (isNaN(-20 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-element)) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))) {
            CTE11.push(0)
        }
        else {
            CTE11.push(-20 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-element)) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))
        }
    });
   // test.innerHTML = '<td id="test">' + CTE11 + '<td>';
    return CTE11
}

function getTM01(){
    let TM01 = [];
    let rs = getRS();
    let freq = getFreq();
    for (let i = 0; i < rs.length ;i++){
        TM01.push(rs[i]/((parseFloat(diameter.value)/2 *25.4/1000)*377*Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(((2.4049/(2*Math.PI*parseFloat(diameter.value)/2 *25.4/1000)*0.3)*Math.pow(10,9)/(freq[i]*Math.pow(10,9))),2)))/(1000/25.4));
    }
    return TM01

}

function getCTM01(){
    let CTM01 = [];
    let TM01 = getTM01();

    TM01.forEach(element => {
        if (isNaN(-20 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-element)) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))) {
            CTM01.push(0)
        }
        else {
            CTM01.push(-20 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-element)) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))
        }
    });
    return CTM01
}


function getAt2(){
    let at2 = [];
    let freq = getFreq();
    freq.forEach(element =>{
       at2.push(Math.pow(((3.8318/(2*Math.PI*parseFloat(diameter.value)/2 *25.4/1000)*0.3)*Math.pow(10,9)/(element*Math.pow(10,9))),2)+1/(Math.pow(3.8318,2)-1))
    });

    return at2
}
function getAt1(){
    let at1 = [];
    let freq = getFreq();
    let rs = getRS();
    for (let i = 0; i < rs.length ;i++){
        at1.push(rs[i]/(parseFloat(diameter.value)/2 *25.4/1000*377*Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(((3.8318/(2*Math.PI*parseFloat(diameter.value)/2 *25.4/1000)*0.3)*Math.pow(10,9)/(freq[i]*Math.pow(10,9))),2)))/(1000/25.4));
    }
    return at1
}

function getCTE01(){
    let CTE01 = [];
    let at1 = getAt1();
    let at2 = getAt2();
    for(let i = 0;i < at1.length; i++){
        if (isNaN((-20*Math.log10(Math.exp(-(at1[i]*at2[i])))*parseFloat(unitInch.value)))) {
            CTE01.push(0)
        }
        else {
            CTE01.push(-20 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-(at1[i] * at2[i]))) * parseFloat(unitInch.value))
        }
        }
    return CTE01
}

function getdata(){
    let data =[];
    let xaxis = getFreq();
    let RTE10 = getRTE10();
    let CTE11 = getCTE11();
    let CTM01 = getCTM01();
    let CTE01 = getCTE01();
    data.push(xaxis,RTE10,CTE11,CTM01,CTE01);
    return data
}


function draw_chart(data) {
    let chart = new Chart(ctx, {

        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: data[0],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'R-TE10',
                data: data[1],
                pointStyle : 'line',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'blue',
                pointRadius: '0'
            },{
                label: 'C-TE11',
                data: data[2],
                pointStyle : 'line',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'orange',
                pointRadius: '0'
            },{
                label: 'C-TM01',
                data: data[3],
                pointStyle : 'line',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'green',
                pointRadius: '0'
            },{
                label: 'C-TE01',
                data: data[4],
                pointStyle : 'line',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderColor: 'red',
                pointRadius: '0'
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            responsive : true,
            scales: {
                xAxes :[{
                    ticks: {
                        min: StartFreq,
                        max: StopFreq,
                        suggestedMin: StartFreq,
                        suggestedMax: StopFreq,
                        stepSize: 0.25,
                    }
                }],

                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min:0,
                        max:10,
                        suggestedMin: 0,
                        suggestedMax: 10,
                        maxTicksLimit: 11,
                        stepSize : 1,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }]
            }

        }
    });
}



function generateChart() {
   // removeData(chart);
    let data = getdata();
    draw_chart(data);
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="inner">
        <tr class="inner">
          <td class="inner"> Attenuation (air) /</td>
          <td class="inner"> <input class="numInput" type="number" id="unitInch"/></td>
          <td class="inner">(in inches)</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="inner">
          <td class="inner" colspan="2">Rectangular WG</td>
          <td class="inner">Circular WG</td>
          <td class="inner">Material</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inner">
          <td class="inner">a (inch)</td>
          <td class="inner">b (inch)</td>
          <td class="inner">Diameter (inch)</td>
          <td class="inner">Conductivity ( x 10<sup>7</sup> S/m)</td>
          <td class="inner">Start Freq (GHz)</td>
          <td class="inner">Stop Freq (GHz)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inner">
          <td class="inner"><input class="numInput" type="number" id='a'/></td>
          <td class="inner"><input class="numInput" type="number" id="b"/></td>
          <td class="inner"><input class="numInput" type="number" id="Diameter"/></td>
          <td class="inner"><input class="numInput" type="number" id="Conductivity"/></td>
          <td class="inner"><input class="numInput" type="number" id="StartFreq"/></td>
          <td class="inner"><input class="numInput" type="number" id="StopFreq"/></td>

        </tr>
      </table>

  <button onclick="generateChart()"><strong>Generate Chart</strong></button>
<div id="chartsize">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
      <script src="js/chart.js"></script>
```

By the way, my chart works completely fine the first time I load the page, then when I update, the chart flickers like crazy when hovering. I added in a lot more code, so that you guys can recreate the chart and figure it out. Please ignore the bad style, I am new to Web Development...

Answer (score -1):

It is because chartjs doesn't redraw the chart, it creates a new one over the old one. You have to make a reset function that gets called before the new chart is drawn

Comment: It would be nice to explain how